# SSDT-BI 2013 slows to a crawl when loading a Data Flow component from an SSIS Pkg

Tags: ssis, ssdt-bi

New to using SSDT-BI 2013.

I have loaded up an SSIS package with a complex Data Flow component. When I double click the data flow component to open it up it takes over a half hour to validate everything.

No errors, just a very long time to load, to the point of being unuseful.

When I open the same thing in Pre SSDT-BI 2013, the same Data Flow opens up immediately.

Can't find anything online about this, anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your computer waiting on?

Comment: Nothing, it's just validating all the tasks under the particular Data Flow I'm opening. Each one takes about a minute to validate, and there are many.

Comment: There will always be a constraint on performance. So, what is happening on your computer when the validation is happening? Is is Network, Disk, CPU, Memory that the package is waiting on?

Comment: We know: it's SQL Server 2014 and you have a "complex data flow" that takes 30 minutes to validate. That's it. We need some details to be able to provide any value

Comment: This is why I have posted the message to get some ideas on what might be happening. The one thing I notice is a taxing of network and disk when this validation running.

Comment: Perhaps if you provided detail about what the complex data flow task is doing. Talk about the associated connection managers - is one of them a web service call to the Curiosity Rover - that's going to take a few minutes to validate.